# How to Use Eclipse Project Path with Different Users in Server

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, server

I have responsibility on develepment an Application which created in Eclipse.  I am able to open project in my computer with Andorid studio after the configuration of project library on Eclipse. In summery i have to setup Eclipse first, configurate libraries path. and then it is possible to import through Android Studio at least l am geting more logical Exceptions or errors.

We have a server with different users.Other user already has Eclipse and able to make changes on his side. **MY QUESTION** is I want to setup Android Studio on my user but should i need to setup Eclipse too? Is it possible to use other users project path on Eclipse. little bit complicated but hope and one had this experiences before. Thank you.

(For Garry)

App -->> Eclipse-->> Android Studio  . To open it in Android Studio Eclipse should be exist is same computer. My question is more like server possibilities. I want to Setup Android.Studio in my user and take the project path from other users Eclipse workspace just asking is it possible or l have to set up Eclipse in my server too?.

Comment: You question is not clear.